# Remove default HtmlEditorField from Page

Tags: silverstripe-4, form-fields

Is there a way to remove/disable the default HtmlEditorField (Content) from a Page in back-end from SilverStripe 4.2.2?

Answer (score 1):

From your Page or subclass of Page:

```
public function getCMSFields()
{
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    $fields->removeByName('Root.Main.Content');

    return $fields;
}
```

Or as an extension:

```
class RemoveContentExtension extends \SilverStripe\ORM\DataExtension
{
    public function updateCMSFields(\SilverStripe\Forms\FieldList $fields)
    {
        $fields->removeByName('Root.Main.Content');
    }
}
```

And apply the extension to your page with YAML config:

```
# File: app/_config/content.yml
MyPage:
  extensions:
    - RemoveContentExtension
```

Comment: Thanks. I was also looking in the official SilverStripe forums cause no one answered, this is the exact answer I got there.